# How to save data from dynamically created text box to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <div>
      <br /><br /><br />
      <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv"       AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover" BorderWidth="2px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="#" HeaderText="#"  HeaderStyle-Height="50px" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Width="50px" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Student_id" HeaderText="Student_id" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff" />

                  <asp:BoundField DataField="RegNo" HeaderText="RegNo" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Student Name" HeaderText="Student Name" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneNO" HeaderText="PhoneNO" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailId" HeaderText="EmailId" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="DOJ" HeaderText="DOJ" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Marks Obt" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-Width="160px" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" class="form-control-smalltxtBox"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Max Marks" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-Width="160px" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tb2" runat="server" class="form-control-smalltxtBox"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
      <br /><br />        
      <br /><br /><br />
  </div>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>

</form>
```

I have created one text box in

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Marks Obt" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-Width="160px" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" class="form-control-smalltxtBox"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And .cs class

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(! IsPostBack)
    {

    }
    DataTable dt = Teacher_DataLayer.getStudent(3);
    gvPop(dt);
}

public void gvPop(DataTable eList)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
        DataRow drw = null;
        int i = 0;
        string id1 = "t1r";
        string id2 = "t2r";
        string sN = string.Empty;
        string sId = string.Empty;
        string sub = string.Empty;
        string mG = string.Empty;
        string mT = string.Empty;
        string ed = string.Empty;
        string et = string.Empty;
        string eaid = string.Empty;
        string regno = string.Empty;
        string phoneno = string.Empty;
        string emai = string.Empty;
        string dt1=string.Empty;
        string dt2=string.Empty;
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("#", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Student_id", typeof(int)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RegNo", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Student Name", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PhoneNO", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmailId", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DOB", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DOJ", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Marks Obt", typeof(string)));
        dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Max Marks", typeof(string)));
        foreach (DataRow dr in eList.Rows)
        {
            int cc = 1;

            foreach (object dc in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                String cd = null;
                if (dc == null)
                {
                    cd = "null";
                }
                else
                {
                    cd = dc.ToString();
                }

                if (cc == 1)
                {
                    sId = cd;
                }
                else if (cc == 2)
                {
                    regno = cd;
                }
                else if (cc == 3)
                {
                    sN = cd;
                }
                else if (cc == 4)
                {
                    phoneno = cd;
                }
                else if (cc == 5)
                {
                    emai = cd;
                }
                else if (cc == 6)
                {
                    dt1 = cd;
                }
                else if (cc == 7)
                {
                    dt2 = cd;
                }
                else if (cc == 8)
                {
                    mG = cd;
                }

                cc = cc + 1;

            }

            i = i + 1;
            drw = dtt.NewRow();
       drw["#"] = i;
            drw["Student_id"] = Convert.ToInt32(sId);
            drw["RegNo"] = regno;
            drw["Student Name"] = sN;
            drw["PhoneNO"] = phoneno;
            drw["EmailId"] = emai;
            drw["DOB"] = dt1;
            drw["DOJ"] = dt2;

            drw["Marks Obt"] = mG;
            //drw["Max Marks"] = maxM;
            dtt.Rows.Add(drw);
         //   dtt.Columns.Clear();
        }

       ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtt;
        gv.DataSource = dtt;
        gv.DataBind();
        SetPreviousData();

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}

public void SetPreviousData()
{
    try
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)gv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("tb1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)gv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[9].FindControl("tb2");

                    box1.Text = dt1.Rows[i]["Marks Obt"].ToString();
                    //box2.Text = maxM;

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ep) { }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dtN = new DataTable();
        DataRow drw = null;
        int rowIndex = 0;
        //dtN.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("#", typeof(string)));
        //dtN.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Student_id", typeof(int)));
        //dtN.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RegNo", typeof(string)));
        //dtN.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Student Name", typeof(string)));
        //dtN.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PhoneNO", typeof(string)));
        //dtN.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmailId", typeof(string)));
        //dtN.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DOB", typeof(string)));
        //dtN.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DOJ", typeof(string)));
        //dtN.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Marks Obt", typeof(string)));
        //dtN.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Max Marks", typeof(string)));
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtV = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            int ww= dtV.Rows.Count;
            if (dtV.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtV.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string sid = gv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
                    int ss = Convert.ToInt32(sid);
                    string nn= gv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Text;
                    string ttt= gv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8].Text;
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)gv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("tb1");
                    string mo = box1.Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

On button click it is not able to find the control of text box I need to save the data entered in text box and student_id.

Answer (score 0):

If a textbox is created inside the TemplateField then this will not be called by click event of the button as this control is bind inside the grid view.

You have to call the row data bound event and get the value from the textbox 
as :-

Step 1:- Add on the grid onrowdatabound="gv_RowDataBound"

In this line of grid

Step 2:- Create in c# end

protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  
  {
   
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        
 {
        
    // Add you logic here
        }
  
}

Else you can do this efficienctly by jquery and ajax call.